# Understanding regular blocks for category $\mathcal{O}$ of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I'm trying to understand the stucture regular blocks of category $\mathcal{O}$ for $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$, given in part iii) of Theorem 5.3.1 in Mazorchuk's Lectures on $sl_2(\mathbb{C})$-modules. The notation of the situation is very specific, so I've tried to write it out the part that is confusing me more simply.

Suppose you have a category with two simple objects, $A$ and $B$. Let $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ be their indecomposable projective covers. It is known that $P(B)$ has composition factors $B,A$, and $P(A)$ has composition factors $A,B,A$ (written in "descending" order, with multiplicity).

The text goes on to say... Since $A\subset P(B)$, and occurs one as a subquotient of $P(B)$, and $P(A)$ is projective with simple top $A$, we have a unique, up to a nonzero scalar, nonzero morphism $\varphi\colon P(A)\to P(B)$. As $B$ occurs with multiplicity one as a subquotient of $P(A)$, and $P(B)$ is projective, we have a unique, up to nonzero scalar, nonzero morphism $\psi\colon P(B)\to P(A)$.

I don't get why there only exist unique nonzero maps up to a scalar, and how it relates to the uniqueness of a composition factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general thing for suitably nice categories like this (i.e. linear categories over an algebraically closed field, which has finite length, finite dimensional Hom-spaces, and where the simple objects have projective covers).

In this sort of category, the dimension of $\operatorname{Hom}(P(A),M)$ is the multiplicity of $A$ in $M$, for any object $M$.

(I assume the word "isomorphism" near the end is a typo for "morphism").

Comment: Thanks, yes, I just fixed the typo. Is there a reference for this result?

Comment: Good question. I think it should be covered in pretty much any thorough book on homological algebra, but I don't have a precise reference handy right now.

Comment: @HailieMathieson Actually, thinking about it, this should be a fairly straightforward exercise. The idea is that you apply hom from the projective to the composition series one step at a time, each time getting a short exact sequence by virtue of projectivity. Then you use that the hom-space from the projective to a simple is always either $1$ or $0$-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks, I think I see how it follows inductively. But why is the hom space from the projective to a simple either 0 or 1 dimensional? I see any nonzero morphism is surjective, so if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are nonzero morphisms from the projective to the simple, there is a endo $\gamma$ of the projective such that $\alpha=\beta\gamma$? Is $\gamma$ necessarily a scalar map, or am I off track?

Comment: Indeed, that endo will be a scalar, since the module is indecomposable.

Comment: Does this follow even though the projective is not necessarily simple? I thought that if it is indecomposable, that just means the endomorphism ring has no nontrivial idempotents.

Comment: Ahh, you are right, we just get that the endoring is local here. We need to use that the module has a simple top, so any map to a simple factors through that, and then use that the endoring of any simple consists of scalars.

Comment: I edited the answer to include the fact that we also need to be working over an algebraically closed field here. I think finite length implies that all Hom-spaces are finite dimensional, but otherwise that would need to be added as well.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft You do need to require finite dimensional Hom-spaces. If $K/k$ is an infinite field extension, then the category of finite dimensional $K$-vector spaces is a $k$-linear abelian category where every object has finite length and which has projective covers, but Hom spaces are not finite dimensional over $k$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Ahh, thanks, I'll edit again.